# Monitortool for Realtime database of Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any tool to monitor the data transfer to my real time database in firebase? To see how many user connect at live time and how much data is transferred?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [usage tab in your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/usage/current-billing/connections) that has most of that information.

We also just released a tool that allows you to profile your database usage. See that tool's [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/profiling-your-realtime-database.html) and [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/database-profile).